# My own backup program was detected as "Win32/Bearfoos.A!ml" virus

Tags: visual-studio, c#, windows-defender

I made this backup program more than a year ago. It had never been detected as a threat before. This morning when it tried to do what it always does, Windows Defender quarantined it, calling it a severe threat "Trojan:Win32/Bearfoos.A!ml"

It uses two DLLs I've written myself, one of them does recursive searches and the other one read/writes files. Basically my .exe reads its config file, overwrites it if a problem occurs, then uses the loaded info to start recursive searches and then copies/compress (using 7za.exe) those files into multiple drives.

It is also Pinvoking kernel32 (GetConsoleWindow) and user32.dll (ShowWindow) since it is a console app.

I'm sure I can add it to exceptions, there is another thread about Avast about a very similar thing that suggested it. I'm just wondering why?
Why now? Why Bearfoos? Why can't Windows Defender detect that I wrote that program myself? Why can't Windows Defender realize it's just copying files around my own local drives? I even added it myself to Windows Task Scheduler, how much more of a green flag does Windows Defender needs!?

I would imagine that's something most programs do, copying and reading files..

Comment: You will need to report the false positive to Microsoft, unless you report the false positive, Windows Defender will continue to detect it as malicious

Comment: Windows Defender is only identifying a possible match, in order to refine the detection processes, the only way to fix this issue is to submit your executable to Microsoft

Comment: It would be interesting to submit the file here https://www.virustotal.com to see what other vendors make of it.

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/377d014ae010d90e0e4c50d9d123cf423d6a8d3d5550f37205d02096892daf21/detection
1/71, only detection was Qihoo-360 as "HEUR/QVM03.0.14C3.Malware.Gen"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would choose Ramhound's comment as the answer: 
"You will need to report the false positive to Microsoft, unless you report the false positive, Windows Defender will continue to detect it as malicious"

I submitted the file to Microsoft yesterday and they responded today.
They have removed the detection and given me steps to purge old definitions and update to the new ones.

Thank you everyone for your input, even the ones that got downvoted.
Here's a page that helped me understand why my program have been detected as a potential malware.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/criteria

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure it is safe add it as an exclusion to Windows Defender.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that in order to exploit this Trojan:Win32/Bearfoos.A!ml all a hacker needs to do is to hack into the homemade backup program instead of hacking into Windows, so there's a possible vulnerability from the backup program even if its code is not intentionally malicious.

Comment: @BanjoDaHousecat Your reputation is now sufficient to comment on most questions (which is arguably what this answer should be).

Comment: @Anaksunaman This is one of those questions that should not be answered by the community.  We can’t possibly know the reason a homemade program is matching a known malware signature.

Comment: Thanks, I've made some shady programs in the past (RAM scanner/injector/extractor) and these were never detected as malware but this simple backup program I made gets detected for afaik, copying and compressing files.

Comment: @karel: I don’t understand your comment.  Can you explain how adding a benign program to the exclusion list creates a vulnerability?

Comment: What I wrote makes the comparison between Trojan:Win32/Bearfoos.A!ml and a horse.

Answer (score 0):

Why did this start to happen now? Likely there was a recent update to Windows Defender that caused it to change its behavior to your program. The detection of malicious software is difficult and the process is not 100% reliable. Mistakes are made. Sometimes malicious software is not detected and sometimes legitimate software is misidentified as malicious.

Windows Defender doesn't try to determine if you wrote the program and thus grant it special privileges. That would be a really bad idea. The programmers do not trust their ability to do this with sufficient reliability. If there was such a facility it would give malware another potential method to evade detection. Windows Defender doesn't have the big picture understanding of the program that you do. It can only check its files for the patterns of known malware and monitor its activity. And it does all of this with the knowledge that things may not be as they appear. Modern malware is very sophisticated and has many tricks so it will appear as something other than what it is. Malware is continually refining its methods to evade detection and security software must refine its detection methods.

Most security software has some kind of exclusion list. But even this isn't as simple as it appears. It must be very carefully managed or malicious software would simply add itself to the list. Malware authors study Windows Defender and other security products, always looking for some weakness they might exploit.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a bit.
I added it to the exceptions because I have to keep my backups up-to-date.
Hopefully the file I sent to Microsoft will help them remove false positives for everyone that have a similar problem.

Comment: I also ran into this issue and this answer was correct for me, as manually updating the Windows Defender definition file resolved the issue. (Note that I was getting this error with my game app built with Unity 2018.3. It did not happen with my builds with Unity 2018.2. In my searches, in addition to this post I've found another recent thread discussing a false positive Win32/Bearfoos.A!ml virus with an upvoted comment saying manually updating Windows Defender definition file resolved the issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/DFO/comments/b61h9j/new_patch_windows_defender_detecting_trojan/ejhd32z/)